# Set a string as the response of a webpage in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

Hi what i am trying to do is not to get the webpage as

```
page.open(url);
```

but to set a string that has already been retrieved as the page response. Can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it is as easy as assigning to page.content. It is usually also worth setting a page.url (as otherwise you might hit cross-domain issues if doing anything with Ajax, SSE,  etc.), and the `setContent` function is helpful to do both those steps in one go. Here is the basic example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.setContent("<html><head><style>body{background:#fff;text:#000;}</style><title>Test#1</title></head><body><h1>Test #1</h1><p>Something</p></body></html>","http://localhost/imaginary/file1.html");

console.log(page.plainText);
page.render("test.png");
phantom.exit();
```

So call page.setContent with the "previously retrieved page response" that you have.

Comment: Thnx, this is very helpful.